# Should I aware a user having low accept rates, system generated names and giving identical answers?

Tags: discussion, support, guidelines

> I know it's a hated post, but is a **GENUINE** question. I was unsure, that's why I asked on Meta

1. Whenever I see a user with username as `user2347894` I ask them to use proper names.
2. Whenever I see a user a new user or basically below 50 rep, or acceptance rate is below 70<sup>*Most of the time only below 50*</sup>, I ask them to make a habit to accept the answer,

   - to increase the acceptance rate
   - to give themselves some bonus point
   - to help other know the working solution
3. When I see identical answers, I ask them not to post such. <sup>*Agreeing on the fact that it might be unknowingly*</sup>

Today, I seem to have offended few users. `Your Common Sense` and `Michael` specially. So, should I stop doing this, or is there a better way to approach the new users, without offending them or sending the negative meaning?

May be they got me wrong, since I only comment on the post I am involved <sup>***because, WHY would I comment on post I don't even see or answer***</sup>, maybe they are thinking I am being greedy or selfish, or over competitive over the reputation.

Comment: 1) not a real problem 2) not a real problem 3) not a real problem.

Comment: I learn by mistakes, and your downvotes mean NOTHING, but nice try.

Comment: `Whenever I see a user with usernames as user2347894 I ask them to user proper names.` That coming from someone called Starx? ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos, Yeah.. any problem with that name?

Comment: @Starx No problem at all, however one could argue that you don't use a "proper name" yourself and you shouldn't be asking others to do so.

Comment: @YannisRizos, That is my name, if one needs my family name, it is my profile too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you don't need to explain, I really don't have an issue with @Starx as a username or any other really. My comment was more to say that if we start asking people to switch from `user2347894` to a more "proper" username, then someone else will come along and say: "hey Starx why don't you use Nabin Nepal as your username"... People will always have their own opinion of what's proper and what's not, and we shouldn't be quick to ask others to conform to what we think it's proper.

Comment: @YannisRizos, are you trying to imply that user2342342 and starx can be both regarded as improper names?

Comment: @Starx I'm saying that no username can be regarded as improper, unless they are offensive, obviously.

Comment: downvotes on Meta [are often used to express disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @gnat, Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Now I get it :P

Answer (score 24):

> Whenever I see a user with usernames as user2347894 I ask them to user proper names.

These are user names that are assigned automatically by the site to users who aren't logged in.  One of the key features of the site is that it's easy to participate.  You don't even have to log in to leave an answer.  Asking people to user a "proper" user name is counter to this notion.

> Whenever I see a user a new user or basically below 50 rep, or acceptance rate is below 70, I ask them to make a habit to accept the answer...

Accepting answers is totally optional.  Keep in mind that you can see someone's 0% acceptance rate after they've asked only 5 questions, so it's possible that they don't have any answers worth accepting.  Telling them to accept an answer just encourages them to accept *any* answer whether it's the right one or not.  Before you tell anyone to accept answers to their previous questions, check to make sure they have a specific answer worth accepting and recommend that.

> When I see an identical answers, I ask them not to post such.

Questions get identical answers all the time within the first few minutes of being posted.  This is normal.  The most complete and correct answers will rise to the top, so there's no reason to comment on the remaining answers.

Comment: Or, basically "Worry about what you're doing and less about what everyone else is doing." :)

Comment: Thanks for a constructive feedback Bill.

Comment: @TimPost, If it is about not worrying about what others do, then I believe features like `comment` or `votes` would be obsolete.

Answer (score 15):

1. None of your business, if they don't want to use a different name it doesn't hurt anyone.
2. If they have 0% accept rate and you suspect they don't even know that they can accept answers, you might post a very polite comment explaining the concept. Having an accept rate below 70% is perfectly acceptable, and if you comment on the accept rate for such users your comments are likely to get flagged and instantly deleted.
3. If they are copying other peoples answers without improving anything that is certainly reason to comment on that. If people post nearly identical solutions at the same time, I wouldn't comment on it, that just happens sometimes.

Comment: You just posted the blunt version of what I was writing, thank you. I particularly cannot stand the "fix your accept rate" comments, and I've actually never heard of the "fix your username" one...

Comment: @Madmartigan, really, but I would love to read that. Would be honoured if you post the `not-so-blunt` answer.

Comment: @Starx: I think the current answers here have covered everything. If there's something you disagree with, please: let it be known.

Comment: @Madmartigan, No, seeing how this meta community reacts to a genuine question asking for a guideline. I just want to read what a harsh version of an answer sounds like.

Comment: @Starx: "Blunt" means "harsh". My answer was going to be less harsh, more polite and lengthy.

Answer (score 4):

As for 1 (one), meh.  I've seen users with more rep than you who have the anon name.  If you want to change it, you will.  Personally, I see low rep + anon name as a signpost as to what kind of user they are.

Please don't do 2 (two).

Frankly, any comments that aren't extremely polite about acceptance rate get deleted whenever they're seen.  And 70% (seventy percent) is **way high** to be bothering people.  Ramp that down to ***under 50% (fifty percent)***.

Think of it this way--you have two questions, it is **completely reasonable** to have a 50% (fifty percent) acceptance rate.

And for 3 (three), it depends.

We see flags all the time about "duplicate answers" and people getting all butthurt about it.  But when we check, the answers are **pitifully trivial** and were submitted *only a few minutes apart*.  Frankly, easy questions get lots of answers.  Once people take the time to answer, they'll still submit it when other answers are coming in.  You don't want to spend a couple minutes answering a question just to throw it away.

Discouraging people from providing correct answers is just wrong.  Discourage the OP from asking questions that are trivial to the point where multiple similar answers come within a short period of time.

No, wait, I take that back.  Don't do that.  Just flag as low quality and move on.

If the answers ***are not trivial***, that's usually indicative of something else.  Don't bother waging a comment war with the person who answered, just *flag for moderator attention*.  We'll need that information to establish a pattern of malfeasance.  If you just leave a comment, we'll never know a user has been copying other people's work.

Comment: Yeah it's usually more like *"hey I beat you by 10 seconds fixing this trivial parse error!"*, not that you plagiarized someone else's hard work. And *"make sure you accept the answer that helped you"* is often code for *"make sure you accept MY answer!"*

Comment: @Madmartigan, So i can fix the OP's code and cannot ask to be accepted? Even though, I am not forced to answer or am forcing to be accepted, right?

Comment: @Starx: Goading people to accept an answer IMO is rude and especially annoying when it's your own, genuinely teaching people that clearly don't know about the feature [why and how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is better. Telling people to "fix your accept rate" is the worst. You might want to clarify what you just asked me because I'm not too sure what you mean. The bottom line is: it doesn't concern you which solution the OP wants to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my opinion on those:

1. Don't ask people to use "proper" names. They can use whatever username they like.
2. I'm constantly annoyed by people saying "if this answer helped you, please accept it" on their own answer. I find it a little arrogant. There will always be people who comment telling users to improve their accept rate, and there's also the 15-minute waiting period for accepting an answer, which users won't always hit exactly. So please don't nag; Stack Overflow already has mechanisms built in that remind askers to accept answers.
3. Keep doing this; duplicate answers are usually bad, *especially* if they're not duplicates of said user's own answers. Of course, if the answers aren't exact duplicates but the questions can be closed as duplicates, do that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly wouldn't worry too much about these issues -

1. Who cares, really? Does it truly matter what username they have? Sure, if you're typing it in a comment or answer it may be inconvenient, but the English language is so contextual, you can go a long way without using somebody's name. Worst case, you can call them "the OP"
2. Whenever I see a comment insisting that somebody accepts an answer or works on their accept rate, I immediately flag it as "too chatty", since it is. Time and again it has been stated on the network that accept rates are irrelevant and don't matter. Write a good answer and you'll get far more rep than an acceptance will give you if it's so important to you. The important thing is to get good questions and answers.
3. If you truly do find an answer that is a duplicate on the same question, go ahead, have fun flagging or downvoting. If they are a little different, but say much the same thing, then it's a much greyer area - you'll need to decide for yourself if it's coincidence or not. On the whole though, there are far worse examples of bad behaviour by users than that.